# Deciding when to use firebase cloud functions instead of only firestore client sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know there’s no correct answer, but I would like to hear your thoughts on a specific example:
Say you have restaurant, and this restaurant has a ordering system with 3 applications:

1. for the restaurant ‘boss’ (for a lack of a better word).
2. for the delivery guys.
3. for the client (ordering food).
4. Works more like an admin account. Therefore I have decided to use cloud functions with the admin sdk to add new users i.e delivery guys accounts. The constructions of menus and dishes are all happening here. I’m currently using only the client sdk for this, simply because it's fast for such simple tasks and cache is a big plus. Now, security wise, my thought is that the ‘boss’ wouldn’t want to tamper with his own documents, so allowing him read and write access to all documents here via security rules seems fine. Would like to hear your thoughts, though.
5. Now, this one is a bit harder, because I’b been only using the client sdk here and allowing read and write access to orders documents for delivery guys. This may be a bit naive since allowing write access to a delivery guy opens up the possibility for tampering with specific fields on the orders doc. I decided to do it that way simply for the speed and cache, but now I’m thinking that I should change it. There is also a chat functionality between the ‘boss’ and the delivery guys. I’m using one document per conversation and if it exceeds 1mb, I have a cloud function that archives older messages if this limit is approached. But since all reads and writes to the chat doc can happen from the delivery guy via client sdk, this leaves it a bit open security wise also (even with more complex security rules). I might be able to solve this if I stopped using one doc and had a doc per message. And with some good security rules I could make this a bit more secure, but not compared to using a cloud function.
6. Here, I have not coded anything on the front end at all, I’m thinking of using cloud functions for security when order requests are submitted.

I really like the speed (for simple queries) and cache when using the client only. If I have something a little more compute heavy or complex I have used cloud functions, which works fine. I also like using cloud functions to trigger stuff after the client sdk has done something. My big concern using cloud functions as a sort of a wrapper or middle man for simple queries too, is the speed on cold starts (and sometimes it’s a bit slow after it's spun up compared to only using client sdk). I’m not a big fan of losing cache and streams that I have with the client sdk. But, since security is very important I’m a bit twisted on what to do.
I’m not asking for any code or the perfect answer, just your thoughts and if you have had any experience with this. I’m leaning towards sticking to the client sdk even for the delivery guys and try to moderate this through even better and complex security rules. And then, maybe try to exploit it myself to see how good it is. What are your thoughts?

I’ve read this article which I found useful: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-us
And watched the video series on cloud functions by firebase, and I found the docs really helpful (both cloud functions and firestore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to handle sensitive information that the client could compromise or manipulate beyond what `Security Rules` can prevent, you should use `Cloud Functions` as *a source of authority*.

1. Firestore + Security Rules
2. Firestore + Security Rules
3. Firestore + Security Rules
4. Cloud Functions only work with the admin-sdk, you can't use the client modules successfully in a node.js environment.
5. Security Rules are your friend, you can deny writes and updates specifically - Chat should be managed through the realtime database
6. use Cloud Functions to finalize orders, cross reference prices, etc. but the rest can be done with Firestore and smart Security Rules to prevent illegal edits.
7. Additionally, you can use Custom Claims to denote who has what role and validate who can do what with rules. so only boss's can issue refunds, wave costs, etc.

Reference:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: I use user id lookups(uid) so I can grab a user's email address, which I DO NOT store in firestore. I can only do that with Cloud Functions (`admin.auth().getUser(uid)`)